# Error 1022 Can´t write duplicate key in table workbench mysql

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench

quisiera pedir su ayuda para solucionar el error 1022 que me salta al hacer el forward engineer en mysql.

El error me lo manda en la siguiente tabla

```
-- Table `Ropa`.`RopaVendida`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Ropa`.`RopaVendida` (<br/>
  `claveRopEx` INT NOT NULL,<br/>
  `No.Cliente1` INT NOT NULL,<br/>
  `No.Emp` INT NOT NULL,<br/>
  `FormaPago` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,<br/>
  `Cantidad` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,<br/>
  `PrecioTotal` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,<br/>
  `RopaVendidacol` INT NOT NULL,<br/>
  INDEX `No.Emp_idx` (`No.Emp` ASC),<br/>
  INDEX `ClaveRopaExis_idx` (`claveRopEx` ASC),<br/>
  INDEX `No.Cliente_idx` (`No.Cliente1` ASC),<br/>
  CONSTRAINT `claveRopEx`<br/>
    FOREIGN KEY (`claveRopEx`)<br/>
    REFERENCES `Ropa`.`Exhibicion` (`claveRopExhi`)<br/>
    ON DELETE NO ACTION<br/>
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,<br/>
  CONSTRAINT `No.Emp`<br/>
    FOREIGN KEY (`No.Emp`)<br/>
    REFERENCES `Ropa`.`Vendedor` (`No.EmpVen`)<br/>
    ON DELETE NO ACTION<br/>
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,<br/>
  CONSTRAINT `No.Cliente1`<br/>
    FOREIGN KEY (`No.Cliente1`)<br/>
    REFERENCES `Ropa`.`Cliente` (`No.Cliente`)<br/>
    ON DELETE NO ACTION<br/>
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)<br/>
ENGINE = InnoDB;<br/>
```

Habia leido que el problema podría derivarse de que las foreign keys tuvieran el mismo nombre asi que las cambie pero sigue marcando el error.

Comment: por que tienes esas etiquetas br?

Comment: Puede que haya índices que ya existan. Ejecuta un `SHOW INDEX FROM Ropa.RopaVendida`  y verifícalo. También, por convención de nombre, a las llaves foráneas se le suele poner el prefijo `fk_` al principio o el sufijo `_fk` al final. Puedes probar esa solución, así estarás seguro de no repetir nada. Como @AlfredoPaz, tampoco le veo sentido a esos `<br />`

Comment: Pues tengo entendido son para que la duda este relacionada a los temas de las etiquetas y pueda ser encontrada

Comment: Ok, A. Cedano intentare eso

Comment: Además [según esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18057522/5587982) los nombres de las restricciones **deben ser únicos en toda la base de datos, no solamente en la tabla**. O sea, es mejor que tengas bien en la cabeza la convención de nombre que vas a usar para las restricciones y aplicarla rigurosamente en cada caso. Puedes usar esta consulta para ver todas las ya usadas en orden alfabético: `SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME<>'PRIMARY' ORDER BY CONSTRAINT_NAME;`

Comment: Hola Adler, veo que nadie te ha dado la bienvenida... Así que aprovecho y te doy la bienvenida a [es.so] y te invito a terminar el [tour] para que puedas ganar tu primera medalla, y te dejo un par de links que ayudarán a que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas. [ask]y [help/on-topic]

Comment: Pues probe ambas opciones, ningun constraint repite el mismo nombre ni las foreign keys y aun marca el error

Answer (score 2):

### El problema

La sintaxis que estás usando es definida así en la documentación:

```
[CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY
    [index_name] (index_col_name, ...)
    REFERENCES tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
    [ON DELETE reference_option]
    [ON UPDATE reference_option]

reference_option:
    RESTRICT | CASCADE | SET NULL | NO ACTION | SET DEFAULT
```

En este caso tú estás asignando un nombre a la restricción... es donde dice `symbol` en la sintaxis.

Pues bien, **ese dato debe ser único, no sólo en la tabla, sino en toda la base de datos**:

> If the `CONSTRAINT` **`symbol`** clause is given, the symbol value, if
>   used, **must be unique in the database**. A duplicate symbol will
>   result in an error similar to: `ERROR 1022 (2300): Can't write;
>   duplicate key in table '#sql- 464_1'`. If the clause is not given, or
>   a symbol is not included following the `CONSTRAINT` keyword, a name
>   for the constraint is created automatically.
>
> ---
>
> Si se proporciona la cláusula `symbol` para `CONSTRAINT`, el valor del
>   símbolo, si se usa, **debe ser único en la base de datos**. Un símbolo
>   duplicado dará como resultado un error similar a: `ERROR 1022 (2300):  No se puede escribir; clave duplicada en la tabla '# sql- 464_1'`. 
>   Si no se proporciona la cláusula, o si no se incluye un símbolo siguiendo
>   la palabra clave `CONSTRAINT`, se crea automáticamente un nombre para
>   la restricción.
>
> <sub>- [Documentación de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)</sub>

---

### Posibles soluciones

#### 1. Establecer una convención de nombre

Si quieres nombrar las restricciones por ti mismo, deberás aplicar una convención de nombre y respetarla siempre. Por ejemplo:

- fk_tabla_columna
- idx_tabla_columna

... o algo parecido

Si quieres saber los nombres de restricciones que hay ya usados y en qué tablas o columnas están puedes hacer una consulta como esta:

```
SELECT 
    TABLE_SCHEMA, 
    TABLE_NAME, 
    CONSTRAINT_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE 
WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME<>'PRIMARY' 
ORDER BY CONSTRAINT_NAME;
```

#### 2. Dejar que el sistema asigne un nombre por sí mismo

En ese caso bastaría con no poner nada en el nombre de la restricción. De todos modos, si usas nombre para los índices únicos, éstos tampoco se pueden repetir en toda la base de datos:

> If neither a `CONSTRAINT` symbol or `FOREIGN KEY` `index_name` is defined,
>   the foreign key index name is generated using the name of the
>   referencing foreign key column.
>
> The `FOREIGN KEY` `index_name` value must be unique in the database.

Comment: Gracias, encontre el problema al parecer si era como habias dicho ya que la foreign se llamaba igual que la primary y al cambiarlo se soluciono