# Error 1826: Duplicate foreign key constraint name, Necesito que puedan ayudarme a ver de donde procede el error

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1826: Duplicate foreign key constraint name 'idPersona'
SQL Code:
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `GlobalCompany`.`Proveedor`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `GlobalCompany`.`Proveedor` (
      `idProveedor` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `idPersona` INT NOT NULL,
      `Compañia` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
      `Estatus` VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`idProveedor`),
      INDEX `idPersona_idx` (`idPersona` ASC) VISIBLE,
      CONSTRAINT `idPersona`
        FOREIGN KEY (`idPersona`)
        REFERENCES `GlobalCompany`.`Persona` (`idPersona`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    ENGINE = InnoDB

SQL script execution finished: statements: 10 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
```

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida. Los nombres de restricciones, índices, llaves... deben ser únicos. El mensaje es claro: *`Duplicate foreign key constraint name...`* está indicando que **el nombre de la llave foránea `idPersona` ya existe**, no puedes usarlo otra vez. Conviene que usas una *convención de nombres*  también para los nombres de tus llaves, índices, etc. [Hace un tiempo respondí a algo parecido aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/171873/29967), la respuesta es buena, modestia aparte, sólo que no ha tenido la repercusión deseada... Pero podría servirte en este caso si le prestas atención.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ese error sucede cuando tratas de generar un **CONSTRAINT** a una tabla con nombre ya existente en la misma.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `GlobalCompany`.`Proveedor` (
  `idProveedor` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idPersona` INT NOT NULL,
  `Compañia` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `Estatus` VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idProveedor`), 
  INDEX `idPersona_idx` (`idPersona` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `idPersona`  -- En esta parte se encuentra el problema.
    FOREIGN KEY (`idPersona`)  
    REFERENCES `GlobalCompany`.`Persona` (`idPersona`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Cambia el nombre que quieres ponerle a tu nuevo constraint. Saludos.

Comment: Perdona mi ignoracia, estoy tratando de aplicar herencia en tres tablas (proveedor, cliente y empleado), las tres poseen el idPersona para conectarla. Debo cambiarles ese nombre a cada una?

Comment: En ese sentido lo que te recomiendo es usar un esquema para nombrar las claves foraneas y las primarias, por ejemplo: FK_tablaDesdeColumna_tablaHaciaColumna así generarías dicha unicidad al nombrarlas y te darán una idea a simple vista de lo que hacen.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Un gusto haberte ayudado. No olvides dar por cerrada la pregunta! Suerte y exitos.